# Creating a unique ID variable using information from two other variables

Tags: group-by, mutate

I have a large dataset of children and their parents (could be one or two),
collected over multiple waves.
The child has a unique ID, but the parents
have just been called parent1 "1" or parent2 "2", so they do not have their own unique ID.
I would like to make a new variable like "New ParentID" below which
gives each parent a unique ID.
`

```
> ChildID = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3")
> StudyWave = c("1","2","3","4","5","2","3","4","6","1","2","3","4","5","6")
> ParentID = c("1","2","1","2","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","1","2","1","2")
> NewParentID = c("1","2","1","2","1","3","3","3","3","4","5","4","5","4","5")
> data=cbind.data.frame(ChildID, StudyWave, ParentID, NewParentID)
> data
   ChildID StudyWave ParentID NewParentID
1        1         1        1           1
2        1         2        2           2
3        1         3        1           1
4        1         4        2           2
5        1         5        1           1
6        2         2        1           3
7        2         3        1           3
8        2         4        1           3
9        2         6        1           3
10       3         1        1           4
11       3         2        2           5
12       3         3        1           4
13       3         4        2           5
14       3         5        1           4
15       3         6        2           5
```

`

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions - I am stuck.

Comment: One challenge with this is the possibility that more than one child have the same parent or parents. Thus, there does not seem to be a concept that "parent" is unique within the dataset.

Comment: That is true. Good point - I will need to check if there were any siblings enrolled - they would have to be twins as the sampled age range was very tight. If it occurred it, it would be rare and I can deal with this later. The 1 and 2 for the parent variable are actually referring to the parent's sex and there were no same-sex parents in the study. So this seems my best option. There is always the possibility that in a follow-up wave P1 was a different person, but I can do some checks using date of birth etc.